# Cartesian product in Gray code order with itertools?

Tags: python, product, python-itertools, gray-code

Is there something like Python's `itertools.product()` that provides the iteration through the Cartesian product of a set of sets in *Gray code order*?  For example, supposing that such a hypothetical generator existed, and it was called `gray_code_product()`, then `gray_code_product(['a','b','c'], [0,1], ['x','y'])` would generate, in the order :

```
('a',0,'x')
('a',0,'y')
('a',1,'y')
('a',1,'x')
('b',1,'x')
('b',1,'y')
('b',0,'y')
('b',0,'x')
('c',0,'x')
('c',0,'y')
('c',1,'y')
('c',1,'x')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of `itertools.product`, the function is equivalent to the following Python code:

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Since a gray code product is about reversing the order of the preceding sequence for each pool, you can use `enumerate` on the previous `result` list while iterating over it to determine if the index is odd or even-numbered, and reverse the sequence of the pool if it's odd-numbered:

```
def gray_code_product(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for i, x in enumerate(result) for y in (
            reversed(pool) if i % 2 else pool)]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

so that:

```
for p in gray_code_product(['a','b','c'], [0,1], ['x','y']):
    print(p)
```

outputs:

```
('a', 0, 'x')
('a', 0, 'y')
('a', 1, 'y')
('a', 1, 'x')
('b', 1, 'x')
('b', 1, 'y')
('b', 0, 'y')
('b', 0, 'x')
('c', 0, 'x')
('c', 0, 'y')
('c', 1, 'y')
('c', 1, 'x')
```